# Mostrar datos en una Tabla HTML con el pluing DataTables

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image]
saludos, estoy trantando de llenar una tabla que usa el pluings datatables, con una consulta de mi base de datos el metodo tiene parametros, pero al mostrar se me queda asi.
agregare el codigo de la vista y el action del controlador.
o si tienen otra manera de llenar la tabla me serviria de mucho.

```
public JsonResult BuscarVentas(string f_desde, string f_hasta, string c_desde, string c_hasta, string estado, string ordenar)
    {
        var data = new List<Ventas>();
        data = objVentasBL.BuscarVentas(f_desde, f_hasta, c_desde, c_hasta, estado, ordenar);
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

function Buscar() {
    var f_desde = document.getElementById("fecha_desde").value;
    var f_hasta = document.getElementById("fecha_hasta").value;
    var c_desde = document.getElementById("cliente_desde").value;
    var c_hasta = document.getElementById("cliente_hasta").value;
    var estado = $("input[name='opc_estado']:checked").val();
    var ordenar = $("input[name='opc_ordenarpor']:checked").val();
    $('#reporte').DataTable({
        "bSort": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": '@Url.Action("BuscarVentas", "Home")',
            "type": "GET",
            "data": { f_desde: f_desde, f_hasta: f_hasta, c_desde: c_desde, c_hasta: c_hasta, estado: estado, ordenar: ordenar },
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
                { "data": "Tipo" },
                { "data": "Numero" },
                { "data": "Serie" },
                { "data": "Codigo" },
                { "data": "Nombre" },
                { "data": "Fecha" },
                { "data": "SubtotalCero" },
                { "data": "SubtotalIva" },
                { "data": "Descuento" },
                { "data": "Iva" },
                { "data": "Neto" },
                { "data": "Estado" },
                { "data": "Operador" },
                { "data": "Obervacion" },
                { "data": "NumeroAutorizacion" }
        ],
        filter: false,
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        language: {
            paginate: {
                first: "Primero",
                previous: "Anterior",
                next: "Siguiente",
                last: "Ultimo"
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Previo respaldo de los archivo involucrados te sugiero lo siquiente; en el controlador en lugar de JsonResult usa ActionResult;en el javascript en vez que parámetro y valor tengan el mismo nombre has algo como "data": { f_desde: f_desde,...} sea "data": { f_desde: fdesde,...} que en js quita el guión (asi con las demas "var" en el js; así no cambias tu controlador). Si el problema persiste apóyate con breakpoints en el controlador que retorna y en el js que recibe y si corresponden a la estructura que se debe enviar/recibir. Éxitos.

Comment: te hace falta la propiedad `bServerSide: true` ya que la informacion la estas obteniendo del servidor.

Comment: ya hice el cambio de los nombres de las variables tamabien cambie en el controlador el jsonresult por actionresult , la propiedad bServerSide:true en que parte del codigo se agrega